# PySimpleGUI RELIEF_SUNKEN Expands When Items Marked Visible But Does Not Shrink When They Are Marked Not Visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm new to PYSimpleGUI and python GUI programming in general. I have made a simple settings relief that I'd like to have expand and contract as needed. Is there a way to get the 3rd picture to resemble the 1st once the elements have been marked visible then not visible?

[image: When Program Starts]

[image: When Items Are Marked Visible]

[image: When Items Are Marked Not Visible]

Picture 3 has the relief still expanded. Is there a way to have it contract again? Thank you!

Please see the code below:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def mkWindow():
    # Layout for the Advanced relief
    layout = [
        [sg.Frame(layout=[
            [(sg.Text('Show Advanced Settings', size=[25, 1]))],
            [sg.Radio('No', "RADIO2", key='_radio_no2_', enable_events=True, default=True, size=(5,1)), sg.Radio('Yes', "RADIO2", enable_events=True, key='_radio_yes2_')],
            [(sg.Output(key='_out_', size=[25, 27], visible=False))]], title='Advanced',title_color='red', relief=sg.RELIEF_SUNKEN)]]

    window = sg.Window('Output Test', layout, finalize=True)

    while True:
        event, wvalues = window.read()
        if(event=='_radio_yes2_'):
            window.Element('_out_').Update(visible=True)
            
        if(event=='_radio_no2_'):
            window.Element('_out_').Update(visible=False)

        if(event==sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            break

    window.close()

mkWindow()
```

Edited to add code. I pared it down to be just the affected frame that still produces the effect when the GUI is generated.

Comment: add some code so we can check the code.

Comment: Just added it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is all in the docs. There is a pin function that does exactly what I was looking for. If added within any kind of frame, the frame auto-sizes as expected. I believe it does shift things within the collapse function by just a bit because it's a layout element within a larger layout, but I got around this by putting the other elements together in another element so they aligned ok. Hope this helps someone out there.

[Cookbook where I got the relevant code.](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-collapsible-sections-visible-invisible-elements)

Code for convenience/in case link breaks at some point:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

> ```
> Demo - "Collapsible" sections of windows
>
> This demo shows one techinique for creating a collapsible section (Column) within your window.
>
> It uses the "pin" function so you'll need version 4.28.0+
>
> A number of "shortcut aliases" are used in the layouts to compact things a bit.
> In case you've not encountered these shortcuts, the meaning are:
> B = Button, T = Text, I = Input = InputText, k = key
> Also, both methods for specifying Button colors were used (tuple / single string)
> Section #2 uses them the most to show you what it's like to use more compact names.
>
> To open/close a section, click on the arrow or name of the section.
> Section 2 can also be controlled using the checkbox at the top of the window just to
> show that there are multiple way to trigger events such as these.
>
> Copyright 2020 PySimpleGUI.org
> ```

```
SYMBOL_UP =    '▲'
SYMBOL_DOWN =  '▼'


def collapse(layout, key):
    """
    Helper function that creates a Column that can be later made hidden, thus appearing "collapsed"
    :param layout: The layout for the section
    :param key: Key used to make this seciton visible / invisible
    :return: A pinned column that can be placed directly into your layout
    :rtype: sg.pin
    """
    return sg.pin(sg.Column(layout, key=key))


section1 = [[sg.Input('Input sec 1', key='-IN1-')],
            [sg.Input(key='-IN11-')],
            [sg.Button('Button section 1',  button_color='yellow on green'),
             sg.Button('Button2 section 1', button_color='yellow on green'),
             sg.Button('Button3 section 1', button_color='yellow on green')]]

section2 = [[sg.I('Input sec 2', k='-IN2-')],
            [sg.I(k='-IN21-')],
            [sg.B('Button section 2',  button_color=('yellow', 'purple')),
             sg.B('Button2 section 2', button_color=('yellow', 'purple')),
             sg.B('Button3 section 2', button_color=('yellow', 'purple'))]]


layout =   [[sg.Text('Window with 2 collapsible sections')],
            [sg.Checkbox('Blank checkbox'), sg.Checkbox('Hide Section 2', enable_events=True, key='-OPEN SEC2-CHECKBOX')],
            #### Section 1 part ####
            [sg.T(SYMBOL_DOWN, enable_events=True, k='-OPEN SEC1-', text_color='yellow'), sg.T('Section 1', enable_events=True, text_color='yellow', k='-OPEN SEC1-TEXT')],
            [collapse(section1, '-SEC1-')],
            #### Section 2 part ####
            [sg.T(SYMBOL_DOWN, enable_events=True, k='-OPEN SEC2-', text_color='purple'),
             sg.T('Section 2', enable_events=True, text_color='purple', k='-OPEN SEC2-TEXT')],
            [collapse(section2, '-SEC2-')],
            #### Buttons at bottom ####
            [sg.Button('Button1'),sg.Button('Button2'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Visible / Invisible Element Demo', layout)

opened1, opened2 = True, True

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

if event.startswith('-OPEN SEC1-'):
    opened1 = not opened1
    window['-OPEN SEC1-'].update(SYMBOL_DOWN if opened1 else SYMBOL_UP)
    window['-SEC1-'].update(visible=opened1)

if event.startswith('-OPEN SEC2-'):
    opened2 = not opened2
    window['-OPEN SEC2-'].update(SYMBOL_DOWN if opened2 else SYMBOL_UP)
    window['-OPEN SEC2-CHECKBOX'].update(not opened2)
    window['-SEC2-'].update(visible=opened2)

window.close()
```